# YouTube deleted my inactive channel. Lost the source computer, forgot linked email creds. Can I recover the videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

About 10 years ago I uploaded some family videos to this channel, and I used to come back to these videos and watch them for the nostalgia. The computer they were on is broken, and I lost it a couple years ago. I have several email accounts old and new, and I have no idea what the email credentials for this account were. I hadn't logged on it for several years because of this. Today I wasn't able to find the channel or any of the videos, and I'm suspecting that it was part of one of the inactive account purges. I already tried the Wayback Machine to recover the videos that were on the channel, but it doesn't have the channel registered at all. Should I try contacting YouTube directly or are there alternative methods I can try? Is there anything I can do? The channel is the only known source for these videos, and I really want to get them back.

Answer (score -1):

I'm the original poster, that was a guest account that I lost access to after creating a registered one.
I'm still checking this